# Login directly into my application when logged in into my system

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have a web application done in Java EE with Struts which has a login screen but I don't want to use it but I should login into my application when I login into my system using my system username and password and all the systems would be connected into the same domain or network and configured in domain server, my application username and password will also have the same login credentials as my system(pc).

Once the user has logged in into his pc it should get connected to the application when entering the URL in the browser and when logged in with some other user in the same system it should get logged in with that user (all the users in the client pc will be configured in the domain)

I don't know how to achieve it,

Please help me

Comment: somehow you might need to access physical cookie stored by your webapp.

Comment: Are you using LDAP for windows authentication??

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try http://spnego.sourceforge.net/index.html using this you can deploy your application in any Java EE server.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Using of windows authentication is not simple task.
You need to configure Tomcat for Kerberos authentication
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html

In your application take user name using: `httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();`

Comment: I'm using Tomcat web server. Provide some examples that will help me lot.

Comment: Did you open the link provided in my answer? It contains step by steps instruction how to do it.